# Installing GNOME 1 or 2.6 or any early 2004 versions of GNOME on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, command-line, gnome, desktop-environments

I would like to experience the older version of computers, but with latest software 
If possible give me a solution using Terminal

Answer (score 0):

**Is not possible.** GNOME has dependencies all over the system with DBUS, libraries, etc. etc.... so it's not worth the work. You can however run an old system in a Virtual Machine with the warning that if something goes wrong there, you have no official support nor here (in Ask Ubuntu). Just go to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com download an ISO and fire up a virtual machine.